# Gemini Pro 1.0 results with "The model response didn't complete successfuly"

Tags: large-language-model, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

For code connecting to Google python vertexai SDK using gcloud authentication:

```
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel, ChatSession

project_id = "<PROJECT_ID>"
location = "us-central1"

vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=location)

model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.0-pro")
chat = model.start_chat()

def get_chat_response(chat: ChatSession, prompt: str):
    response = chat.send_message(prompt)
    return response.text
```

I keep getting the below error that does not say anything. Any idea how to decode the `Finish reason: 2.` from the below error and how to fix it?
I am programmatically sending multiple prompts approx. 4,5k but around 150-th prompt i keep getting this error:

```
  File "/Users/l028/dev/reach-collective-ml-playground/hf_1_0/qualification_check/gemini.py", line 42, in get_chat_response
    response = chat.send_message(prompt)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/l028/.pyenv/versions/playground_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py", line 727, in send_message
    return self._send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/l028/.pyenv/versions/playground_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py", line 822, in _send_message
    self._response_validator(
  File "/Users/l028/.pyenv/versions/playground_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py", line 658, in _validate_response
    raise ResponseValidationError(
vertexai.generative_models._generative_models.ResponseValidationError: The model response did not completed successfully.
Finish reason: 2.
Finish message: .
Safety ratings: [category: HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
].
To protect the integrity of the chat session, the request and response were not added to chat history.
To skip the response validation, specify `model.start_chat(response_validation=False)`.
Note that letting blocked or otherwise incomplete responses into chat history might lead to future interactions being blocked by the service.
2024-03-08 14:35:48 [error    ] Error in LLM request: The model response did not completed successfully.
Finish reason: 2.
Finish message: .
Safety ratings: [category: HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
, category: HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT
probability: NEGLIGIBLE
].
To protect the integrity of the chat session, the request and response were not added to chat history.
To skip the response validation, specify `model.start_chat(response_validation=False)`.
Note that letting blocked or otherwise incomplete responses into chat history might lead to future interactions being blocked by the service.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

No search results in this case.

Answer (score 2):

"Finish reason 2" corresponds to the "MAX_TOKENS" finish reason. Which indicates that you have set the max_tokens configuration for the model, and your output has reached that token limit.

See https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1/GenerateContentResponse#FinishReason for a general description:

> The maximum number of tokens as specified in the request was reached.

You can see in the [internal definitions](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/b91edf52e2b993c3301a419ad89b473c31c60cc3/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/types/content.py#L535) for the ProtoBuf enumeration why this is defined as 2.

Comment: How do you know MAX_TOKENS corresponds to `2`?
How can I change the max_tokens limit?

Comment: Which library are you using (language and how you're adding the package to your environment)? This suggests the library is setting it to some default. Are you using any other frameworks?